# Why isn't my function doing anything?

Tags: php

What I want to happen: I want to use a function to check for errors and keep those errors from being placed in my database.

Details (and what is currently happening): I have a function that checks for errors that I defined. If an error is found, it is placed in an array. After all errors are found, I exit my function. I then place the names I want (that come from a form in a CSV format) and I upload them to my database. However, after the first iteration, a name with an error is still placed into the database even though it was found in my function for error checks. How can I stop those names with errors from being placed into my database?

Also note that in my HTML/PHP form I do start the session and I do unset the session as well.

Code for my process:

```
session_start();

$formInputNames = $_POST['names'];

$active = (isset($_POST['activate'])) ? $_POST['activate'] : false;
//checks if activate checkbox is being used
$email = '@grabby.com';
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$fullnames = explode(", ", $_POST['names']);

if ($active == true) {
    $active = '1';
    //sets activate checkbox to '1' if it has been selected
}
/*----------------------Function to Insert User---------------------------*/
         A Function is here to place names and other fields in database.
/*-------------------------End Function to Insert User--------------------*/

/*-----------------------Function for Errors---------------------*/

function errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames){
    if ($formInputNames == empty($fullname)){
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        }
        elseif ($formInputNames == empty($nameSplit[0])) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: First Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        }
        elseif ($formInputNames == empty($nameSplit[1])) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Last Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z, ]/', $fullname)) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Illegal Character Found in: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        }
}

/*-----------------------------End Function for Errors------------------------*/

/*--------------------------Function for Redirect-------------------------*/

function redirect($url){
    $string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $string .= 'window.location = "' .$url. '"';
    $string .= '</script>';

    echo $string;
}

/*-------------------------End Function for Redirect-----------------------*/

//  Connect to database
     I connect to the database here

foreach ($fullnames as $fullname) {
    $nameSplit = explode(" ", $fullname);

errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames);

            //opens the database
I Open the database here

        $firstName = $nameSplit[0];//sets first part of name to first name
        $lastName = $nameSplit[1];//sets second part of name to last name
        $emailUser = $nameSplit[0].$email;//sets first part and adds email extension

        newUser($firstName,$lastName,$emailUser,$active,$conn);
}//ends fullnames foreach

if (count($_SESSION['error']) == 0) {
    redirect('viewAll.php');
} else {
    redirect('form.php');
}
```

I hope I'm clear with what I'm trying to achieve but if I'm not let me know. Google, this site and others have not helped me in the best way. Thanks in advanced!

EDIT: What I mean by 'my function isn't doing anything'

I want my function to stop the names with errors from entering in my database. I am trying to achieve this by testing the names I inputed in the function and keep them from entering. What happens now (and what is working) is, the error is produced and the message is shown if there is an error.

And if that hasn't helped, look at it this way.

```
if (empty($fullname)){
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        } elseif (empty($nameSplit[0])) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: First Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        } elseif (empty($nameSplit[1])) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Last Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        } elseif (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z, ]/', $fullname)) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Illegal Character Found in: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
        } else {
            $firstName = $nameSplit[0];//sets first part of name to first name
            $lastName = $nameSplit[1];//sets second part of name to last name
            $emailUser = $nameSplit[0].$email;//sets first part and adds email extension
    newUser($firstName,$lastName,$emailUser,$active,$conn);
       }
```

The above (along with the rest of my code) will do what I'm trying to achieve.

So basically what I'm trying to achieve, how do I use that finial else statement in my function.

Comment: What is `$formInputNames` and the possible values it could have?

Comment: $formInputNames values come from a html/php form where users can enter names in CSV format. e.g. Bill Houston, Manny Tiny, Chris Hem

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `$formInputNames == empty($fullname)` to do?  Whatever it is, I guarantee that it's not what it actually does.  See [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I want to know if $formInputNames has anything in it. Hence why I'm using empty. It does work for me though because if I test those errors, they produce the messages I'm asking for.

Comment: @Alei You see where your mistake is now? In your `if`, you are asking if `"Bill" == true`.

Comment: "I want to know if $formInputNames has anything in it."  Then what you want is `if(empty($formInputNames)){//something}`

Comment: @PatrickGregorio I get it, but why is it working?

Comment: @Alei Is it working? I thought you said in your question that your function is doing nothing?

Comment: I should have been more clear, I will edit to what I mean.

Comment: @Alei Please take a look at what @Patrick Q provided you because that is how you check if `$formInputNames` has anything in it.

Comment: The code at the bottom of your update looks like just what you want.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Have I tried it in my function? Yes. It doesn't work though. If I take $firstName and the rest out of the main, my newUser function doesn't know what they have in them. Also if I take my newUser call out of main nothing works, my program just dies.

Comment: @Alei Are you getting any errors or warnings? `I connect to the database here` and `I Open the database here` isn't commented out so I'm guessing that's where you are having problems?

Comment: No errors or warnings. I forgot to comment them out but I have the actual code, I just didn't want to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've combined parts of your original code with most of the code in your update.  The basic idea is that you'll have `errorCheck()` return a boolean.  That boolean is checked to see if you should proceed and insert a record into the db.

```
session_start();

$formInputNames = $_POST['names'];

$active = (isset($_POST['activate'])) ? $_POST['activate'] : false;
//checks if activate checkbox is being used
$email = '@grabby.com';
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$fullnames = explode(", ", $_POST['names']);

if ($active == true) {
    $active = '1';
    //sets activate checkbox to '1' if it has been selected
}
/*----------------------Function to Insert User---------------------------*/
         //A Function is here to place names and other fields in database.
/*-------------------------End Function to Insert User--------------------*/

/*-----------------------Function for Errors---------------------*/

function errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames){
    $isValid = false;

    if (empty($fullname)){
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    } elseif (empty($nameSplit[0])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: First Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    } elseif (empty($nameSplit[1])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Last Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    } elseif (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z, ]/', $fullname)) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Illegal Character Found in: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    } else {
        $isValid = true;
    }

    return $isValid;
}

/*-----------------------------End Function for Errors------------------------*/

/*--------------------------Function for Redirect-------------------------*/

function redirect($url){
    $string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $string .= 'window.location = "' .$url. '"';
    $string .= '</script>';

    echo $string;
}

/*-------------------------End Function for Redirect-----------------------*/

//  Connect to database
     //I connect to the database here

foreach ($fullnames as $fullname) {
    $nameSplit = explode(" ", $fullname);

    if(errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames))
    {
        //opens the database
        //I Open the database here

        $firstName = $nameSplit[0];//sets first part of name to first name
        $lastName = $nameSplit[1];//sets second part of name to last name
        $emailUser = $nameSplit[0].$email;//sets first part and adds email extension

        newUser($firstName,$lastName,$emailUser,$active,$conn);
    }
}//ends fullnames foreach

if (count($_SESSION['error']) == 0) {
    redirect('viewAll.php');
} else {
    redirect('form.php');
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. The reason why OP still has erroneous names saved in the database is because the checking of errors doesn't control whether the data is saved or not.

Comment: YES! except when I typed Bill Houstin, Manny T636iny, Chris Hem it shout out that they were all errors of an illegal character, and none of the good names were placed in the database. It should only say Manny T636iny is an error but still but the other good ones in.

Comment: @Alei When I run a [slightly modified version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/274e9ff68867a4f43cfb7013c2f1d9dc59ae5324) (just so I can get it to run), I do not see that being the case.  The only illegal character notice that I get is for Manny T636iny.  What makes you think you as seeing the error for all names?  The above code doesn't actually do anything with `$_SESSION['error']`, which is the only place you keep track of the errors.

Comment: my fault, put $_SESSION['error'] = array(); above the start of my foreach loop. What prints for me, when I run it is essenitally this line - Error: Illegal Character Found in: Bill Houstin, Manny T636iny, Chris Hem. That line appears three times after just one run, just like that. And none of those good names are entered in the database.

Comment: @Alei But where are you printing the errors?  There is nothing in the code above that does that.  Also, do a `var_dump($formInputNames);` right after `$_POST['names'];`.  Something tells me it's not exactly what we're expecting.

Comment: I got it. it was becuase I was incorrectly calling my function

Answer (score 0):

```
$formInputNames == empty($fullname)
$formInputNames == empty($nameSplit[0])
$formInputNames == empty($nameSplit[1])
```

`empty` returns a `boolean` value but you are checking if it is equal to `$formInputNames`.

I'll try to improve your code:

```
function errorCheck($fullname,$nameSplit,$formInputNames) {
    if (empty($formInputNames) && empty($fullname)) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    } elseif (empty($formInputNames) && empty($nameSplit[0])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: First Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    } elseif (empty($formInputNames) && empty($nameSplit[1])) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Last Name Missing Here: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    } elseif (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z, ]/', $fullname)) {
        $_SESSION['error'][] = '<br><br> Error: Illegal Character Found in: '.$fullname.'<br><br>';
    }
}
```

I used `&&` instead of `||` because I don't really know what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I see, but all those statements still work. As in, they still produce errors when there is one.

Comment: I want to check if there are any names (or any text at all) in formInputNames once, and then check if the firstName, lastName and if there are anything but a-z in formInput Names. So my update uses @Patrick Q suggestion.